# How to lock device orientation in iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, orientation

I have a problem with my app. I cannot lock the orientation of my app. All I need to do is to lock one view controller to landscape mode and the rest are portrait.

This is hierarchy of my app.

```
*Navigation Controller
     *TabBarController
          *ViewControllers
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: this is the code I used

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}


- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

Comment: You can edit your question to post the codes.

Comment: Also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503423/shouldautorotate-behavior-in-ios-8

Answer (score 0):

You only have to return `NO` from `shouldAutorotate` and the landscape orientation from `supportedInterfaceOrientation` in the one you want to be in landscape.

On the other, return `NO` too from `shouldAutorotate` method and portrait orientations mask from `supportedInterfaceOrientation`.

In all the viewControllers :

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate { 
     return NO; 
 }
```

In the one you want in landscape :

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{ 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape; 
} 
-    (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation { 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft; 
}
```

In the controllers you want in portrait :

```
 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{ 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; 
} 
-    (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation { 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait; 
}
```

Comment: note that iOS 7 and 8 use different methods to determine UI orientation

Comment: i have tried this code 

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    
}

it works but how can I landscape just one view controller?

Comment: It's this that I said.  You have to implements the methods I tell in your UIViewControllers.

Comment: How can I do that? could you please teach me how? Sorry I'm noob. Thank you very much.

Comment: its still rotating. what is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Use below 2 this methods to lock device orientation to landscape.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
[super supportedInterfaceOrientations];
return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft |  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    return YES;
}
// Return YES for supported orientations
return NO;
}
```

Comment: it works but my problem is that my view are still rotating how can I lock the orientation in a certain view and rest are portrait. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With NavigationController

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

these method are never called , if you use 'show segue(push)'.

change segue 'showDetail' instead 'show'

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response but I'm not using storyboards in this project. How can i do that?