# Allow multiple orientations for only one UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I want the general orientation of my app to be portrait, but for one specific `UIViewController` (VC2B)  I want the user to be able to tilt the device for landscape orientation. (VC2B has a navigation bar)

I have tried different types of code but without luck.  Ideally I would like to to enable rotation in only `UIViewController` (VC2B).  But this seems impossible, instead it seems you have to enable all the orientations in the General section and then turn them off programatically - is this really true?

Anyway I have tried various things

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue) | Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight.rawValue) | Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue)
}
```

The below answer suggest overriding `shouldAutorotate` to false, but that does not work if the page is loaded in landscape mode, then it is just stuck on landscape.

[Allow all orientations for only one view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655784/allow-all-orientations-for-only-one-view-controller)

**Question**:  How can I in a tidy way, without adding code to **all** my `UIViewController`s, allow multiple orientations for only one `UIViewController`?

Comment: How are you showing that specific viewcontroller? as Modal? or Pushing into NavigationController?

Comment: NC ------> VC1B    ---push--->   VC2B

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to lock device orientation in iOS 7 and iOS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962727/how-to-lock-device-orientation-in-ios-7-and-ios-8)

Comment: You can create a BaseViewController, add Portrait rotation to that, assign that to all of your ViewController, and implement all rotation separately for that viewcontroller(*VC2B*)

Answer (score 0):

Do the following as I did this when I faced same situation:

enable the desired orientations in the General Info Screen
in each ViewController.swift, **override** the autorotation function with either **true** or **false** (true for the one that should rotate, false for the others)

Comment: That only works if all the VC's are loaded push, fails if loaded modal.  The View will then load in whatever orientation the phone has at the time.